# condaの環境から出るとneovimのaleが動かなくなる

Tags: python, vim, conda

conda環境でneovimのaleでflake8やjediを使いたいと考え以下の操作でインストールしました。

1. `conda create -n neovim`
2. `conda install -c conda-forge neovim`
3. `conda install -c conda-forge flake8`
4. `conda install -c conda-forge jedi`
5. init.vimに `let g:python3_host_prog = 'path/to/miniconda3/envs/neovim/bin/python'` と追記

しかし、仮想環境neovimを出てしまうとneovimでパイソンのリントができません。どのようにすれば仮想環境外でもリントできるでしょうか。

以下にneovim仮想環境のconda listを示します。

```
ca-certificates           2018.10.15           ha4d7672_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2018.10.15            py36_1000    conda-forge
flake8                    3.6.0                 py36_1000    conda-forge
greenlet                  0.4.13                   py36_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.13.1                py36_1000    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1                hfc679d8_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3    conda-forge
mccabe                    0.6.1                      py_1    conda-forge
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36h2d50403_3    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1                  hfc679d8_1    conda-forge
neovim                    0.3.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2p               h470a237_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pip                       18.1                  py36_1000    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pyflakes                  2.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python                    3.6.6                h5001a0f_3    conda-forge
readline                  7.0                  haf1bffa_1    conda-forge
setuptools                40.5.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.25.3               hb1c47c0_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.8                ha92aebf_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.32.2                   py36_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4                h470a237_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h470a237_3    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1):

pyenvユーザですが，同様の方法でpython関係の設定を行っている者です．

> 5. init.vimに `let g:python3_host_prog = 'path/to/miniconda3/envs/neovim/bin/python'` と追記

万が一本当にこの通り設定しているのなら，pythonへのパス設定が間違っていると思います．

`'path/to/miniconda3/envs/neovim/bin/python'`の部分は，環境によって異なります．
自身の環境でcondaがどこにpythonを置いているか確認してみてください．

仮想環境neovimに入り，`which python`をコマンドラインで叩けばわかるはずです．

Comment: 書き忘れていましたが、質問ではプライバシー上の理由から正確なパスをぼかして書きました。ちゃんと仮想環境のパイソンへのパスを記述しています。